# Safely iterating through a Blocking Collection?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, concurrent-collections

I have the following peice of code:

```
    private static void FetchAllDataForAllNodesInCache()
    {
        var tasksList = Cache.TreeNodeItemsCollection.Select(nodeToEnrich => new Task(() => InsertQueuesIntoNode(nodeToEnrich))).ToList();

        var count = tasksList.Count;
    }

    private static void InsertQueuesIntoNode(TreeNode toEnrich)
    {
        // blagh do something?
    }
```

My question is, do I need to use a Take or Try Take method when setting up a new task or is the above fine? I mean, don't I need to remove my item safely from the collection and then add it back in again when the task has completed safely. The only gurantee I can provide for anyone who wants to answer my question is that, no two tasks will be working with the same node from 'Cache.TreeNodeItemsCollection'.

I am yet to add in some code to kick off the tasks but that will be added once I know of my current set-up is fine or not?

Comment: Use one of the collections under `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace or use `lock` to sync access to collection.

Comment: I don't see a blocking collection in your code.

Comment: 'TreeNodeItemsCollection' is the BlockingCollection. I should have made this clear from the start - sorry!